# How to make images to go out of the div when width is over the max-width?

Tags: css, image, css-float

I have a page with a text and images inside it, with a style float:right.
I'd like to set max-width for the text, but let the images to go outside the text.

Is it possible to do it with a pure css, without javascript?

This is how I would like to see it on a normal screen and wide screen:

```
+----------------------+    +-------------------+--------------+
|                      |    |                   |              |
|  TEXT         TEXT   |    |                   |              |
|              +-------+    |                   |   +-------+  |
|              |       |    |                   |   |       |  |
|              |  IMG  |    |     TEXT          |   |  IMG  |  |
|              |       |    |                   |   |       |  |
|              +-------+    |                   |   +-------+  |
|                      |    |                   |              |
|  TEXT         TEXT   |    |                   |              |
|                      |    |     TEXT          |  BACKGROUND  |
|                      |    |                   |              |
|              +-------+    |                   |   +-------+  |
|              |       |    |                   |   |       |  |
|              |  IMG  |    |                   |   |  IMG  |  |
|              |       |    |     TEXT          |   |       |  |
|              +-------+    |                   |   +-------+  |
|                      |    |                   |              |
|  TEXT         TEXT   |    |                   |              |
|                      |    |                   |              |
+----------------------+    +-------------------+--------------+

                            <-----MAX-WIDTH----->
```

Comment: Now there is nothing special. Just like `<div class="text"> Some text <img src="..." style="float:right"> Some more text </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3 [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
     .aClass {}
     .anotherClass {}
     /* properties in here only apply when the viewport is wider than 600px */
}
```

Using this method you can have the text flow around the images by default, but if the viewport is wide then you override that CSS and position the images outside the container div using negative margins or absolute positioning.

[More about responsive web design with CSS.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Ok, I will try to make float for the normal screen and relative for the wide screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`style="position:absolute;right:100px;"` may give you what you want. Note that you might not need to specify `float:right` if you have `position:absolute`.

You should not have img that are inside a div appear outside of that div. The images should be maybe siblings of the div instead of children.

Comment: I think that some text would be hidden under the pictures if you have position:absolute.